# Center a div with flex = 33

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, angularjs-material

Thank you for taking a look at my question. I have a div that is expanding across the page horizontally, which is what I want. I have 4 buttons in the div and I am using:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-around center" layout-sm="column" layout-fill layout-wrap >
```

Which is good. However, it is taking up the whole div so the buttons look awkwardly spaced out. So I added `flex="33"` and now they are spaced out, but stuck in using only a third of the page which is what I want and it looks good. The issue I have is it is taking up the first third and I want it to use up the second third of the page. Is there a way to do this with out creating unnecessary divs to occupy the first third?

Here is the complete code:

```
<div flex="33" layout="row" layout-align="space-around center" layout-sm="column" layout-fill layout-wrap class="pageNavButtons">
    <div ng-repeat="button in navPage" layout="column" layout-align="center center" style="color: #ffffff">
        <label>{{button.div}}</label>
        <span></span>
        <md-icon md-svg-src="{{button.icon}}"></md-icon>
    </div>
</div>
```

I do not have any CSS with it yet.

Images:

Before `flex=33`
[image]

After adding it:
[image]

Comment: We'd need the output HTML and base CSS in a working demo.

Comment: That said, `flex="33"` is *probably` related to the width (I'm not familiar with what I *think* is Angular notation.)...not centering. From what I know of `flexbox` I suspect the issue is the **space-around** in `layout-align="space-around center"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by either using `flex-offset="33"` or by adding `layout-align="center" layout="row"`on the parent. I would probably use the second one.

```
<div div layout="row" flex-offset="33">
    <div flex="33" layout="row" layout-align="space-around center" layout-sm="column" layout-fill layout-wrap class="pageNavButtons">
        <div ng-repeat="button in navPage" layout="column" layout-align="center center" style="color: #ffffff">
            <label> {{button.div}}</label>
            <span>----- </span>
            <md-icon md-svg-src ={{button.icon}}></md-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center">
    <div flex="33" layout="row" layout-align="space-around center" layout-sm="column" layout-fill layout-wrap class="pageNavButtons">
        <div ng-repeat="button in navPage" layout="column" layout-align="center center" style="color: #ffffff">
            <label> {{button.div}}</label>
            <span>----- </span>
            <md-icon md-svg-src ={{button.icon}}></md-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/mPVdRK